# c++ win32 prevent context menu from closing

Tags: c++, winapi, contextmenu

I would like to prevent the context menu from being closed in my win32 c++ application. I want to prevent closing the submenu when user clicks on a submenu item. Which message do i have to implement/override?

Comment: The normal behavior of context menu is to be hidden after a menu is selected. You can re-open it. BTW, `winapi` (Win32 API) works with C and your c++ tag/title is not correct. MFC requires C++.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't done win32 dev in a while, however just random thoughts that come to my mind - maybe will be helpful:

1) maybe you could try to show the context menu again right after the item was clicked

2) or do it the complex way - find, then subclass the context menu window, then intercept WM_CLOSE/WM_DESTROY messages

Overall this seems to be a weird thing to want to implement.  Maybe the menu is not the right UI element if you want to keep it on the screen after the selection was made.  Maybe you need a modeless dialog instead?

Comment: it's a setting combo box bind to right click on notifyicon and is really annoying if you want to change 2 settings at once (because it closes every time you select a item). In C# you can prevent this behavior with event.cancel

Comment: You cannot cancel a win32 menu dismiss. What you can do instead is create a menu-like window that has whatever behaviors you like (including no-auto-dismiss). See the FakeMenu sample in the Platform SDK for an example.

Comment: @blejzz .NET gives you a lot more control than Win32.  This may not be possible. Good luck!

Comment: @Raymond Chen, you're wrong. Please see this example: http://codexpert.ro/blog/tag/wh_msgfilter/

Comment: I stand corrected. There is no mechanism supported by the menu itself, but I guess you could "go outside the box" and change the message processing rules with hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following [article](http://codexpert.ro/blog/tag/wh_msgfilter/).

Comment: The page for that link has almost nothing on it. Please add actual content when posting an answer instead of just a link. That way, if the link becomes a 404, your answer will still be useful.