# winapi - prevent a context menu from closing

Tags: winapi

I have a scenario where a context menu should be keep open. I have used an WH_MSGFILTER hook for receving a context menu messages. When an user clicks on the context menu item a dialog window for choosing color is opened:

```
case WM_LBUTTONUP:
{
    if (colorSelected)
    {   
        //pMSG->message = WM_NULL; doesn't prevent context menu from closing when a dialog box is opened below
        currentColor = chooseColor(selectedMenuItemPos); //call ChooseColor winapi 
    }
    break;
}
```

[Here](http://codexpert.ro/blog/tag/wh_msgfilter/) is an example how to prevent a context menu from closing where an user clicks on the context menu item. As you can see in the above code I have also tried that method but it doesn't work when a dialog box is opened. Is it possible to keep a context menu open in such scenario ? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570918/c-win32-prevent-context-menu-from-closing) is a similar question but it can be resolved using a method described above. I'm not interested in other solution, for example a fake menu window. I'm just curious if it is technically possible in winapi.

Answer (score 2):

[`WH_CBT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks#wh_cbt) hook can prevent menu from closing via handling [`HCBT_DESTROYWND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644977(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#parameters).

Register the hook: `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, CBTProc, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());`

Hook procedure:

```
HRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(
    int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam
)
{
    switch (nCode)
    {
    case HCBT_DESTROYWND:
    {
        if((HWND)wParam == gMenuWindowHandle)
        {
            return 1; // Return 1 to prevents closing window.
        }
    }
    break;
    }

    return ::CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Result (`About` is an menu item and `About WindowsProject21` is a dialog box):

[image]

Comment: I know that you have posted a minimal example but HCBT_DESTROYWND should return 1 only for the particular window - HWND for the menu in this case. There is one problem: when you close a dialog window a menu is "frozen".

Comment: Ok, but the main problem remains - when you close a dialog window a menu is "frozen".

Comment: @Irbis Yes, there are also other problems, like when you drag your main window the "frozon" popup window (menu) will be left in initial position instead of moving along with the main window and as a part of it. Every time you click a menu, a window shows for monitoring mouse events and take an action based on specified event, then it complete  its work, destroyed and disappeared, it is its default working way. When you change its default working way, like prevent it from closing, you have responsibility to handle all of rest part. It may be not solved by one question.

Comment: @Irbis If you want to keep the menu window open and clickable as usual, it is suggested to create a menu-like window that has whatever behaviors. Refer to FakeMenu sample. If you want to keep the window for a short time, then close it. Next time you can click on the menu again it will open a new window. If this is what you are looking for, yes, it can be done that you can record the opened window and destroy it at later time to prevent other problem. But still it is not a good practice.